Are there objective standards proposed in the literature for estimating the likelihood of a hypothesis when empirical statistics are unavailable?
To motivate this question, let’s consider a controversial example: the origin of life on Earth. We lack empirical statistics about life spontaneously emerging in any setting. There are no documented instances of anyone observing life emerging anywhere. Instead, our consistent empirical experience, without exception, is that living organisms arise from prior living organisms. If we naively reverse this pattern, it would imply an infinite regress of living organisms, which is untenable if the universe had a beginning at the Big Bang.
Thus, let us consider three different hypotheses for the origin of life on Earth:

H1: Abiogenesis.
H2: Life on Earth was designed by aliens.
H3: Life on Earth was created by God.

What these three hypotheses have in common is the absence of empirical statistics to support them. We have never observed abiogenesis, aliens designing life, or a deity creating life. Therefore, under a frequentist interpretation of probability, this lack of observation suggests a frequentist probability of 0 for each hypothesis.
Given this situation, where statistical evidence offers no guidance in comparing competing hypotheses, have philosophers proposed anything resembling an objective standard for estimating the likelihood of such hypotheses? Or at least a standard for ranking hypotheses by likelihood?
I ask this because I am feeling a bit pessimistic about the existence of such standards, and I would like to be proven wrong. But if we entertain the pessimistic case and grant that none exist, discussions about the relative likelihood of hypotheses in the absence of empirical statistics may reduce to subjective judgment calls. This, in turn, risks turning such debates into stalemates, where one person’s subjectivity stands against another’s, and without an agreed-upon framework to resolve the impasse, these debates may lack any meaningful resolution.
Please remember to cite references to support any proposed standard (hence the reference-request tag).

Note on Terminology: Instead of discussing "likelihood," some people may prefer terms like "probability," "plausibility," "epistemic probability," or others. I welcome answers proposing alternative terminology, provided they explain their meaning, offer a justification for their choice, and cite relevant references to support their proposal.

One can appeal to general statistical laws under certain conditions. For example, "Assuming you are human and a normal distribution for human heights, you are  99.73% likely to be within three standard deviations of the mean value of human height" is a true statistical assessment of a physically meaningful hypothesis with a sample size of one (your height).

@gs but the notion of what that 99.73% figure means is subject to interpretation and depends on what kind of probability you’re working with. Some philosophers even argue that for the single case that is you, talk of probability is meaningless. Anyhow, the kinds of hypotheses mentioned in the question that we’re often interested in aren’t privy to this kind of statistical analysis in the first place.

Empirical frequencies of complex processes (like emergence of life) are almost never available, that is not how statistics works. Hypotheses about them make predictions, often about simpler constituents, those predictions are tested, and Bayesian rules are used to update probabilities. Abiogenesis predicts synthesis of organic compounds in conditions of young Earth, and some of that has been confirmed in labs. Its developed form, RNA world, makes even more subtle and detailed predictions. Alien seeding also makes predictions, about alien tracks, etc., but those came up short so far.

Maybe I can think up a more complete answer....but to me, this seems mostly a definitional mirage.  I.e., design arguments are not talking about frequentist probability in that sense, and so any criticisms that assume this definition don't apply.  I.e., we can calculate the odds that a fair coin will flip 100 heads in a row by chance within a given timeframe, without ever having observed it even once.  The definitions are more a matter of convenience, and a valid response to the design argument must address its conceptual content, rather than simply responding by using different definitions.

Where did all this rain come from? Yesterday, there wasn't a cloud in the sky. Perhaps, in the absence of any evidences or likelihoods, we should move on to something else.

You say 'these debates may lack any meaningful resolution'. They do. Why do you think there is no agreement on the matter after eons of debate world-wide and many tens of ridiculous questions on the topic on this site.

Agreed. I’m not sure the disagreement has to do with the nature of the topic though, but rather people’s willingness to fall for confirmation bias and stick to their prior beliefs


“A likelihood function (often simply called the likelihood) measures
how well a statistical model explains observed data by calculating the
probability of seeing that data under different parameter values of
the model”, see likelihood function.

But “when empirical statistics are unavailable” one cannot estimate the likelihood of hypotheses.
It follows without invoking philosophy.

So you are agreeing with my pessimistic case. So debates about the origin of life are a waste of time.

The origin of life - on earth and otherwhere - is an active field of research in molecular chemistry. It is based on theory and experiment like often in science. - Armchair philosophy or just speculation seems not the right way to find the solution.

Theoretically, we could find evidence one way or the other - the lack of any evidence for some abiogenetic mechanism would probably reduce the probability that abiogenesis was what happened. But if we find alien life of any kind that is completely different from ours (i.e. runs on something other than DNA), that would make the other two options less likely. Debates, on the other hand, are quite pointless in my opinion; at the moment we haven't enough information to tell one way or the other.

The closest philosophers have to this is the concept of objective bayesianism.

Objective Bayesians contend that, in addition to coherence, there is another epistemic virtue or ideal that needs to be codified into a norm for prior credences: freedom from bias and avoidance of overly strong opinions

Objective Bayesians, rather than Subjective Bayesians (who allow any sort of priors for hypotheses) are often sympathetic to the principle of indifference.

The principle of indifference is a philosophical concept that states that when there is no relevant evidence to suggest one outcome is more likely than another, then each outcome should be assigned an equal probability.

However, this principle is contested and can (arguably) lead to paradoxes as discussed in the same linked article above. Bayesianism in general has a system for updating your priors using the likelihoods of data given certain hypotheses. This updating system is generally agreed upon by both subjective and objective Bayesians. Their difference comes from how they define the prior probability of hypotheses which you seem to be getting at despite your confused usage of the word likelihood here.
Objective Bayesianism is ultimately only objective in spirit since terms like “freedom from bias” only beg the question for what is enough to constitute that freedom. In your case, there would be no objective way to deal with the theories you mentioned. Personally, I think there’s an obvious reason for this, which is that there is no “correct” probability for a hypothesis in the first place. A theory like abiogenesis is either true or false. Reality is not in degrees.
In short, there is no way to escape judgment calls. But this isn’t something unique to the “likelihood” of hypotheses. This is prevalent throughout all of philosophy. As such, there’s no need to be a pessimistic skeptic due to this.
Firstly, there is a middle ground between “anything goes” and the kind of ideal, objective standard you seek.
Secondly, one can for example inquire as to whether one is consistent in their beliefs even if their system of making judgment calls is ultimately subjective.
For example, a person who seems to require more evidence for a theory that they have an emotional attachment to rather than another theory can be shown to be prone to cognitive bias and so this kind of self inquiry can help resolve an impasse.

Can you illustrate how objective bayesianism would deal with the particular case raised in my question,  namely, abiogenesis vs. aliens vs. God?

Edited my answer to discuss that

"Firstly, there is a middle ground between “anything goes” and the kind of ideal, objective standard you seek." - And what is this "middle ground"?

@user80226 that would deserve its own lengthy answer and philosophers have debated this. I would suggest to find resources on “epistemic permissivism”. See here: https://philpapers.org/browse/epistemic-permissivism#:~:text=In%20contrast%2C%20epistemic%20permissivism%20is,a%20particular%20body%20of%20evidence.

How about summarizing the main points of that paper? It doesn't have to be a lengthy answer.

@user80226 it’s more of a definitional paper rather than anything, and contrasts between the viewpoint that two people can be both rational with respect to the same evidence, or one is rational and the other not. Ultimately, from an epistemic standpoint, I lean a little more towards almost all of philosophy being judgement calls. I think of them as bets. But you can make a bet by flipping a coin or you can make a bet by gathering as much information as possible.
